gcc error: `undefined symbol: ares_dns_parse` when using c-ares library
I was trying to build a C program that uses the ares_dns_parse function from the c-ares library. I have decided to install the latest v1.31.0 according to the installation steps here: https://github.com/c-ares/c-ares/blob/main/INSTALL.md, as follows:
$ wget https://github.com/c-ares/c-ares/releases/download/v1.31.0/c-ares-1.31.0.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf c-ares-1.31.0.tar.gz
$ cd c-ares-1.31.0
$ ./configure
$ make 
$ sudo make install

I have set up a simple C program as follows:
ares_test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ares.h>


int main()
{
  char buf[1000] = "test buffer";
  size_t buf_len = sizeof(buf);

  ares_status_t ares_res;
  ares_dns_record_t *dnsrec;

  ares_res = ares_dns_parse((const unsigned char *)buf, buf_len, 0, &dnsrec);

  if (ares_res != ARES_SUCCESS){

          perror("ares_dns_parse() error: \n");
  }

 return 0;
}


Compiling with gcc with -v verbose flag:
gcc ares_test.c -lcares -I /usr/local/include -o ares_test -v

Output:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-9QDOt0/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' '/usr/local/include' '-o' 'ares_test' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1 -quiet -v -I /usr/local/include -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu ares_test.c -quiet -dumpbase ares_test.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase ares_test -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/ccpRO6c2.s
GNU C17 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) version 9.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=95 --param ggc-min-heapsize=123533
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) version 9.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=95 --param ggc-min-heapsize=123533
Compiler executable checksum: 01da938ff5dc2163489aa33cb3b747a7
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' '/usr/local/include' '-o' 'ares_test' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -I /usr/local/include --64 -o /tmp/cc8nt9W0.o /tmp/ccpRO6c2.s
GNU assembler version 2.34 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' '/usr/local/include' '-o' 'ares_test' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccDBFgG1.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro -o ares_test /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. /tmp/cc8nt9W0.o -lcares -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' '/usr/local/include' '-o' 'ares_test' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

Running binary:
$ ./ares_test

Output:
./ares_test: symbol lookup error: ./ares_test: undefined symbol: ares_dns_parse

However, with the exact same C program, just with the last argument (&dnsrec) to the ares_dns_parse() function removed, and compiled the exact same way as above (minus the -v flag), the following error is shown:
ares_test.c: In function ‘main’:
ares_test.c:13:14: error: too few arguments to function ‘ares_dns_parse’
   13 |   ares_res = ares_dns_parse((const unsigned char *)buf, buf_len, 0);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/ares.h:417,
                 from ares_test.c:2:
/usr/local/include/ares_dns_record.h:1008:28: note: declared here
 1008 | CARES_EXTERN ares_status_t ares_dns_parse(const unsigned char *buf,

This tells me that gcc is able to find the ares_dns_parse function in /usr/local/include/ares_dns_record.h.
Note: I am running this from an Ubuntu machine.
Are there any additional linking required, or any steps I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Sorry that's too much code. An emtire server to show resolve a dns call? And run it via sudo no less? No thanks. A [mre] should be minimal. Call ares_dns_parse with a hardcoded buffer and that's it. It doesn't matter what you put oin the buffer either, since the program supposedly doesn't run anyway. Also please separate building and running. It is kinda important to know which stage ends up with an error. And post the error messages in their entirety verbatim.

I have updated according to your comment. I have also added additional details I have tested.

What happens is that /usr/local/lib is not searched by default at run time, so your library is not loaded. Type ldd ./ares_test, what do you see? You may want ro add -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib to your build command.

The following is the output from ldd ./ares_test:
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc09959000)

        libcares.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libcares.so.2 (0x00007f1862a01000)

        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1862804000)

        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f18627e1000)

        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1862a35000)


and oh yes thank you, the additional flag -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib removes the error. May I know why it helps though?

THis doesn't check out. Are you sure you have libcares.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libcares.so.2?

Yes, is there a reason it should not appear?

Sorry, wrong order of operations. It should appear when you add -Wl,... and some other path should appear if you don't.

With help from @n. m. could be an AI, the solution is to simply add an extra flag to the gcc compilation command: -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib:
$ gcc ares_test.c -lcares -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib -o ares_test

Well, but the value given to -rpath might not always be /usr/local/lib though, but depends on the argument you provided to the --prefix flag for the ./configure command.
For example if the value is /usr/randompath:
$ ./configure --prexix=/usr/randompath

Then, the additional flag would be -Wl,-rpath=/usr/randompath/lib
$ gcc ares_test.c -lcares -Wl,-rpath=/usr/randompath/lib -o ares_test

In fact, the -I /usr/local/include is not even required.
